# installing BOTH 32 and 64 bit mysql-connector-odbc on centos

Tags: centos7, mysql-connector

Is it possible to install BOTH 32 and 64 bit mysql-connector-odbc?  I get a weird yum error that I don't know how to resolve.  I need both because we are transitioning to a 64 bit app.  Obviously, if the 32 bit mysql-connector-odbc can be used with a 64 bit app, then how would I do that.

My yum run, with the error:

```
+ sudo yum install mysql-connector-odbc -y
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.advancedhosters.com
 * epel: mirror.cogentco.com
 * extras: mirror.jaleco.com
 * updates: mirrors.advancedhosters.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-connector-odbc.i686 0:8.0.16-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libodbcinst.so.2 for package: mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.16-1.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libodbc.so.2 for package: mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.16-1.el7.i686
---> Package mysql-connector-odbc.x86_64 0:8.0.16-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libodbcinst.so.2()(64bit) for package: mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.16-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libodbc.so.2()(64bit) for package: mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.16-1.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package unixODBC.i686 0:2.3.1-11.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libltdl.so.7 for package: unixODBC-2.3.1-11.el7.i686
---> Package unixODBC.x86_64 0:2.3.1-11.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libtool-ltdl.i686 0:2.4.2-22.el7_3 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package              Arch   Version        Repository                     Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 mysql-connector-odbc i686   8.0.16-1.el7   mysql-connectors-community-32 3.7 M
 mysql-connector-odbc x86_64 8.0.16-1.el7   mysql-connectors-community    3.7 M
Installing for dependencies:
 libtool-ltdl         i686   2.4.2-22.el7_3 base                           49 k
 unixODBC             i686   2.3.1-11.el7   base                          410 k
 unixODBC             x86_64 2.3.1-11.el7   base                          413 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install  2 Packages (+3 Dependent packages)

Total size: 8.3 M
Installed size: 42 M
Downloading packages:
Running transaction check
Running transaction test


Transaction check error:
  file /usr/share/doc/mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.16/INFO_BIN conflicts between attempted installs of mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.16-1.el7.i686 and mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.16-1.el7.x86_64

Error Summary
-------------
```

I tried looking up various combinations of the "conflicts between attempted installs of" error, but nothing really seemed to address my issue.

Comment: Use a 32-bit distribution until you can cut over. These mixed distributions are a nightmare. Apple's macOS had a solution with one library having two stubs, one 32-bit, one 64-bit, but I don't think Linux can deal with that. Consider using a [Docker container](https://www.docker.com) as a stop-gap measure for library isolation.

Comment: Then why does the odbcinst.ini configuration support both in the same config file?  One references lib64 ( Driver64 and Setup64 ), other references just lib ( Driver and Setup ).  Also, why does it matter that there is a conflict with documentation?

Comment: If you want to try it, that's your prerogative. I'm just suggesting isolation, like inside a container, will give you enough separation this is not a concern.